# Adding top padding to a Navigation list class

Tags: css, padding

Here is the html:

```
<header>
  <img src="cp_logo2.png" alt="Cycle Pathology" />
    <nav class="vertical">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Events Page</a></
         <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Rose Hill Rally</a></li>
There are <li> under this as well as four <li class-="newgroup">
```

Here is the assignment for the CSS Style Sheet:
"If the list item belongs to the newgroup class, add atop padding space of 25 px to add a bigger gab between that list item and the previous list item." 
Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty obvious:

```
.newgroup {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```